# Python Ctypes: convert list of integers to array of shorts

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, endianness

I'm trying to convert a list of integers to a ctypes array of shorts. I want to then assign that array to a field in a BigEndianStructure. I tried doing this:

```
from ctypes import BigEndianStructure, c_uint16

class Test(BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('arr', c_uint16 * 10)]

num_list = [45, 56, 23]
tester = Test()
short_array = c_uint16 * 10
tester.arr = short_array.from_buffer_copy(bytes(num_list))
```

But it didn't like that the list was smaller than what it expected:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    tester.arr = short_array.from_buffer_copy(bytes(num_list))
ValueError: Buffer size too small (3 instead of at least 20 bytes)
```

So then I tried to extend the list and convert the ints to big endian bytes:

```
new_list = num_list[:10] + [0]*(10-len(num_list))
buffer = b''
for item in new_list:
    buffer += item.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
tester.arr = short_array.from_buffer_copy(buffer)
```

But it complains about the buffer not being a "be_array" which I'm assuming has to do with the endianness:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    tester.arr = short_array.from_buffer_copy(buffer)
TypeError: incompatible types, c_ushort_Array_10 instance instead of c_ushort_be_Array_10 instance
```

Am I overthinking this? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get around this?

Edit: clarification from the comments, the corresponding structure in C has a uint16_t arr[MAX_LEN], where MAX_LEN=10. So I want to send a 0 filled array if the passed array is not the full MAX_LEN.

Comment: To clarify, is your desired output in C `uint16_t arr[10] = {45, 56, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`? (Assuming you're on a big-endian system, of course)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The corresponding structure in C has a uint16_t arr[MAX_LEN], where MAX_LEN=10. So I think it would expect to get a 0 filled array if the passed array is not the full MAX_LEN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is minimal support for a BigEndianStructure.  You can't create a `c_ushort_be` or `c_ushort_be_Array_10` but you can assign to a string slice if your list is shorter than your array and it will do the right thing:

```
from ctypes import *
from binascii import hexlify

class Test(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [('arr', c_uint16 * 10)]

num_list = [45, 56, 23]
tester = Test()
tester.arr[:len(num_list)] = num_list
print(hexlify(bytes(tester)))
```

Output (hexadecimal representation of raw structure):

```
b'002d003800170000000000000000000000000000'
```

See also the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module.  It might suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I knew it had to be easier than what I was doing. It also works for a LittleEndianStructure, which is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I overthinking this?

Yes, massively. There's no need to mess with `from_buffer_copy` or `bytes` at all. If the only reason that you need a big-endian structure is that you're on a big-endian system, then using a regular structure instead will make your life a lot easier:

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_uint16

class Test(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('arr', c_uint16 * 10)]

num_list = [45, 56, 23]
tester = Test()
short_array = c_uint16 * 10
tester.arr = short_array(*num_list) # Or num_list[:10] if it might be too long
```

---

If you really want to use big-endian even if you're on a little-endian system, then things get more complicated. First of all, it will result in `45`, `56`, and `23` becoming `11520`, `14336`, and `5888` in C. If you don't want that to happen, then you want the above solution. If that really is what you want, then read on. In this case, `short_array = c_uint16 * 10` is useless to you, since it has native endian-ness, but the array you need to put in your structure must be big-endian. I'm not aware of a way to get the type of a big-endian array to make all at once, so you'd need to fill it manually, like this:

```
from ctypes import BigEndianStructure, c_uint16

class Test(BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('arr', c_uint16 * 10)]

num_list = [45, 56, 23]
tester = Test()
for i, x in enumerate(num_list): # Or num_list[:10] if it might be too long
  tester.arr[i] = x
```

Comment: Thanks, your second example is more of what I was going for because I need the BigEndianStructure not the native endianness.